# Incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression X cannot be converted to CompetionStage<X>, after adding a layer of thenApply

Tags: java, compiler-errors, completable-future

I get the following error

```
[ERROR] AccountServiceResource.java:[165,38] incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
[ERROR] Response<okio.ByteString> cannot be converted to java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage<Response<okio.ByteString>>
```

about the following line

```
return checkExceptionCauses(exception);
```

where `checkedExceptionCauses` is a method that returns a `Response<ByteString>`

```
private Response<ByteString> checkExceptionCauses(Throwable exception) {
     // ...
}
```

The question, is why it trying to convert it to a `CompletionStage<>` all of a sudden? Here's (a simplified version of) the original code that compiled fine:

```
private CompletionStage<Response<ByteString>> getAccountById(RequestContext rc) {
    return accountServiceClient.getAccount().thenApply( getAccountResponse -> {
      AdAccountResponse payload;
      payload.map(getAccountResponse);
      return Response.forPayload(serializePayload(payload));
    }).exceptionally(exception -> {
      LOG.error("Lorem ipsum");
      return checkExceptionCauses(exception);
    });
}
```

So you see, we were returning whatever a `.thenApply()` returned, or an `.exceptionally()`. (Admittedly, I'm not well-versed in completable futures, so probably that's why I'm confused here.)

But okay, I feel that my modification does the same thing:

```
private CompletionStage<Response<ByteString>> getAccountById(RequestContext rc) {
    return accountServiceClient.getAccount().thenApply( getAccountResponse -> {
      AdAccountResponse payload;
      payload.map(getAccountResponse);

      // *** BEGIN CHANGES *** //
      Request salesforceRequest = Request.forUri(FORCEIT_GET_BUSINESS_INFO_URI, "GET").withPayload(businessInfoRequestPayload);
      return httpClient.send(salesforceRequest, rc).thenApply(salesforceResponse -> {
        if (salesforceResponse.payload().isPresent()) {
          // ...
        } else {
          // ...
        }
        AdAccountResponse payload;
        payload.map(getAccountResponse);
        return Response.forPayload(serializePayload(payload));
      });
      // *** END CHANGES *** //

    }).exceptionally(exception -> {
      LOG.error("Lorem ipsum");
      return checkExceptionCauses(exception);
    });
}
```

All I've done is add another layer of `.thenApply()`. But I have my inner `.thenApply()` return the same thing the original code was returning, and my outer `.thenApply()` just passes it up.

So why am I now all of a sudden getting a complaint about converting to a `CompletionStage`? I tried this just for kicks:

```
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(checkExceptionCauses(exception));
```

And not surprisingly, I now got a complaint higher up about returning a `CompletionStage<Response<ByteString>>` instead of a `Response<ByteString>`.

Comment: What is the return type of `getAccount()`? What is the return type of `forPayload(...)`?

Comment: @Andreas - `getAccount()` returns a `CompletionStage<Response<ByteString>>`. Sorry, I didn't think that was necessary to say since I didn't change that in between edits, but I see why it may be relevant. `forPayload` is a chained method that still returns the `Response` object.

Comment: @Yahya - Yes, but why :-) I cannot figure out what is different between my before and after...

Comment: @Yahya - omg... I replaced the first `thenApply` with a `thenCompose` and it worked. I'll wait to post an answer in case you want to write an answer for some rep :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thenApply` is used if you have a synchronous mapping function.

According to the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenApply-java.util.function.Function-):

> Returns a new `CompletionStage` that, when this stage completes
>   normally, is executed with this stage's result as the argument to the
>   supplied function.

On the other hand, `thenCompose` is used if you have an asynchronous mapping function that returns a `CompletableFuture`. In other words, `thenCompose` returns a future with the result directly, rather than a nested future.

From [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-):

> Returns a new `CompletionStage` that is completed with the same value as
>   the `CompletionStage` returned by the given function.
>   When this stage completes normally, the given function is invoked with
>   this stage's result as the argument, returning another
>   `CompletionStage`. When that stage completes normally, the
>   `CompletionStage` returned by this method is completed with the **same
>   value**.

So try to replace `thenApply` by `thenCompose`.